# Cons cells Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am super beginner. So don’t be surprise that my question is that easy.

I have following list `(1 3 ((2))(7))`

And I have to reconstruct that list just with the function `cons`.

I have no idea how to cons the third element of the list.

Maybe there is someone how could help me!

Thanks a lot!

```
(cons '1 (cons '3 (cons '(2) (cons '(7) nil))))
 --> (1 3 (2) (7))
```

There are still missing some brackets. I have no idea to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The fix for your problem would be this: **(please keep reading tho, this is not the final answer)**

```
(cons '1 (cons '3 (cons (cons '(2) nil) (cons '(7) nil))))
```

You were really really close with your solution: `(cons '1 (cons '3 (cons '(2) (cons '(7) nil))))` the thing was that, as you said, there was some parethesis missing on the 2. You managed to make `(2)` which is a list containing 2, but the goal was to make a `((2))` which means: A list containing a list containing 2. So we simply changed `'(2)`  to `(cons '(2) nil)`

Now, that being said, i would consider the use of '(2) as cheating, since if you are allowed to use quotes, you could just do `'(1 3 ((2)) (7))` or the equivalent `(quote (1 3 ((2)) (7))))` and you are done. Clearly there is no challenge in that. So what you probably have to do is use ONLY cons without beign able to use quote at all, in that case the soluion would look like this:

```
(cons 1 (cons 3 (cons (cons (cons 2 nil) nil) (cons (cons 7 nil) nil))))
```

And this is a lot more pure, which is probably what you were assigned to do, this WOULD be a valid answer

We could even go extreme purist and replace nil with `()` (They both represent the empty list) and we get this

```
(cons 1 (cons 3 (cons (cons (cons 2 ()) ()) (cons (cons 7 ()) ()))))
```

Which really shows the beauty of "Everything is a list" which lisp has. But let's face it, that's overkill

Now, if something is still not clear, you might need to study a little bit more on what lists really ARE in lisp. I'm not the best person to explain this (I'm a programer, not a teacher) but i can try. I do recomend you to do a little bit of research on your own tho, that beign said:

## Theory time!

### Feel free to skip this whole if you fell you are solid on the theory

Cons is one of the fundamental building blocks of lisp, it's a very very simple concept, It's a container that holds two... things. What those things are is beyond the scope of what we need to know, but is a very intresting topic on its's own. The important point is that we can call cons on two things (Eg. two numbers) like this `(cons 3 4)` and the interpreter would print something that looks like this `(3 . 4)`, you can get the first argument by calling `car` and the second one by calling `cdr` like this:

```
(car (cons 3 4)) ; 3 

(cdr (cons 3 4)) ; 4
```

Well, i said that a cons can hold to things, not just numbers, for example we could hold a number and the empty list `NIL` like `(cons nil 7)` and as you might expect `(car (cons nil 7))` indeed returns `NIL`

We can also place a cons inside another cons! like this `(cons (cons 3 4) (cons 6 7))` Which you could think of like a tree with to branches (So a binary tree), and each one of them also having two branches, and ad the end of those is the node holding each of the numbers. We can still use `car` and `cdr` to get the left and right elements (`(3 . 4)` and `(6 . 7)` respectively)

Ok, that easy, a little bit too easy, how are we suposed to get lists by just being able to make pairs? The answer is abstraction! There is a concept in computer science called a Linked List. There are many ways to make it in a lot of programing languages, usually with pointers and stuff. The idea behind a Linked List is that you can encode a list of things a series of Nodes, one "node" is nothing more than a thing that hold a value, and a way to get the next node. We also need to encode the concept of "There ISN'T a next node, you reached the end of the list". And if you are clever enough, you can start to see how the pieces come together and allows you to construct a linked list using just `cons`.

If we wanted to make a linked list (Which i would simply call a "list") of numbers in lisp we can define nodes using cons. We can place a number as the first argument and the next node as the second argument. We can also denote the terminating node, that tells us that we are at the end of the list with nil, so if then next node is nil, that means we reached the end of the list

The boring example would then be a list containing one element which would look something like this

```
(cons 8 nil)
```

We could get the element in this node with `car`, which would return 8, and get the next node with `cdr`. In this case `cdr` will return NIL, which is the terminating node and that would signal that we are in the last node of the list

It's not very exiting, but it's all we need to model our linked list! Lets try making a list of two elements now

```
(cons 8 (cons 9 nil))
```

Same logic as before, we can get the value of the first node with `car` and we can get the next node with `cdr` which would return the `(cons 9 nil)`. And we can get the value of that node with `car` and *it's* corresponding next node which is the terminator and we reached the end

And indeed, if you type `(cons 8 (cons 9 nil))` into the interpreter, you will get the same result as if you were to type (list 8 9). Since behind the scenes the ARE the same thing

Lets make a few more examples:

What about a list that contains one list? for example, we learned how to do `(8 9)` but what about `((8 9))`?

We could simply take our whole `(cons 8 (cons 9 nil))` thing and place into another node `(cons VALUE NEXT)` where next is nil (There is no next element) and value is our whole list, resulting in: `(cons (cons 8 (cons 9 nil)) nil)`. And indeed, the interpreter prints `((8 9))`

Armed with this knowledge let's give another go at your exercise. But let's be more fundamental about it, we can see that is is a list of four elements (lets call them `a` `b` `c` and `d`). We can make a list of them by connecting 4 nodes so:

```
(cons a
  (cons b 
    (cons c
      (cons d nil)
    )
  )
)
```

now let's thing about what `a` `b` `c` and `d` are. We can tell a and be are just numbers so they can be replaced pretty easily like this

```
(cons 1
  (cons 3 
    (cons c
      (cons d nil)
    )
  )
)
```

`d` is also pretty easy, is just a list containing a single element, we made one of those already and it looks like this `(const 7 nil)` so we can replace that as well

```
(cons 1
  (cons 3 
    (cons c
      (cons (cons 7 nil) nil)
    )
  )
)
```

And finally `c` is the most complicated one, because it is a list holding a list, but we can handle that no problem, we simply make a list of a single element `(cons VALUE nil)` and replace value with another list of a single element `(cons 2 nil)` and replace value with it so we get `(cons (cons 2 nil) nil)`. Which we can replace in our final answer to get:

```
(cons 1
  (cons 3 
    (cons (cons (cons 2 nil) nil)
      (cons (cons 7 nil) nil)
    )
  )
)
```

Or back in a single line:

```
(cons 1 (cons 3 (cons (cons (cons 2 nil) nil) (cons (cons 7 nil) nil) )))
```

And there we go! You probably get the drill now it's a very simple concept, but it has a LOT of implications, which take a while to wrap your head around, and when you eventually do it, you get a glimpse of the ultimate power of the lisp programing language

Comment: Super! Thank very much Sebastian! Your Explanation helped me. But I have still a problem. The following list ist given `((Fat Cat) (In da ((House)) It) (Might eat (the (treats))))` same task. My solution ist still super wrong. And of course I don't know why. `((cons (cons '(Fat Cat) nil) (cons '(In da House) nil) (cons 'it nil) (cons (cons '(might eat) (cons'(the) nil) (cons (cons'(treats) nil))))))`
 Maybe you could help me?!

Comment: Try using the same problem solving technique i used in the answer to explain how i came up with the final answer. In this case `((Fat Cat) (In da ((House)) It) (Might eat (the (treats))))` is fundamentally a list of three things `(a b c)` where `a` is `(Fat Cat)` , b is `(In da ((House)) It)` and c is `(Might eat (the (that's)))`. So you can try to focus on figuring out  how you can represent those `a` `b` and `c` independently and then replace them in `(cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))`. Of course you could then decompose each one of `a` `b` and `c` into it's own list with their own `a` `b` etc

Comment: Also! Please do not use quotes, that might be a big part of what you are getting confuse, here you ONLY need to put a quite behind words like `'House` (Since `House` would just give an error for being an undefined symbol). In lisp `'(5)` and `(5)` are very different things. Doing something like '(might eat) like you are doing in your example is agains the spirit of the exercise since you should NOT be allowed to use quotes, if you could the solution would just be `'((Fat Cat) (In da ((House)) It) (Might eat (the (treats))))`. You might want to read a bit more in what the `quote` does in Lisp

Answer (score 5):

**We can write us a program to do it.**

```
CL-USER 85 > (defun consify (expression)
               (cond ((atom expression)
                      (typecase expression
                        (null      expression)
                        (symbol    (list 'quote expression))
                        (otherwise expression)))
                     (t
                      (list 'cons
                            (consify (first expression))
                            (consify (rest  expression))))))
CONSIFY
```

Above returns the CONS expression.

```
CL-USER 86 > (consify '(1 3 ((2))(7)))
(CONS 1 (CONS 3 (CONS (CONS (CONS 2 NIL) NIL) (CONS (CONS 7 NIL) NIL))))
```

We can now evaluate the result from above:

```
CL-USER 87 > (eval (consify '(1 3 ((2))(7))))
(1 3 ((2)) (7))
```

Same with your other expression:

```
CL-USER 88 > (pprint (consify '((Fat Cat)
                                (In da ((House)) It)
                                (Might eat (the (treats))))))

(CONS (CONS 'FAT (CONS 'CAT NIL))
      (CONS (CONS 'IN (CONS 'DA (CONS (CONS (CONS 'HOUSE NIL) NIL)
                                      (CONS 'IT NIL))))
            (CONS (CONS 'MIGHT
                        (CONS 'EAT (CONS (CONS 'THE
                                               (CONS (CONS 'TREATS NIL)
                                                     NIL))
                                         NIL)))
                  NIL)))

CL-USER 89 > (eval (consify '((Fat Cat)
                              (In da ((House)) It)
                              (Might eat (the (treats))))))
((FAT CAT) (IN DA ((HOUSE)) IT) (MIGHT EAT (THE (TREATS))))
```

Comment: Considering the fact that this was likely a school assignment, i feel just giving a program that answers the question might be a little inmoral, it'll definitely be considered cheating and will prevent the person from actually learning the concept at hand... That being said, pretty clever function dude

Comment: @SebastianGudiño : the person learns something much better: one can easily write program generating programs, which is one of the main reasons why Lisp exists

Comment: Agree! But you are not really teaching him how to make a program tho, you just gave him the program, where is the teaching/learning part?

Comment: @Sebastian Gudiño : there are many ways to learn. I've learned a lot by reading code from others.

Comment: Also a good point